# What is difference between opengl and xwindows system?

Tags: graphics

I have searched lot and couldn't find anything. I'm confused and don't know how OpenGL and Xserver work together. As far as i know OpenGL translate the client's program code to driver commands(correct me if i'm wrong please). And i want know how graphic drivers work in Linux. I mean where dose graphic drivers reside?
If you know a proper books please let me know.
Please help me to find out.

Comment: This question is really bread and not really geared towards the Stack Overflow format. You might try asking on an OpenGL or XWindows specific forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xserver provides a window to OpenGL on which 3D image is rendered. OpenGL only provides ways to rasterize a image and does not care about on which "window" its being rendered. That work is done by X Window system in Linux and Win32 Api in Windows. Also there are libraries available like Glut and Qt which does this windowing job. So in other words you can consider XServer as a canvas on which OpenGL does its drawing.

So OpenGL is a spec and graphic drivers contain its implementation. Graphic driver takes care of how your application specific calls are translated to acceleration hardware specific calls. Its same for windows and linux both.